# How to add a github project in android studio using only compile line?

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control

I would like to add my github library in android studio.
One way is to download it and add it as a module but i would like to add in the gradle using that compile line in build.gradle.

For example, I can add UniversalImageLoader library using this tag :-

```
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
```

Comment: In order to do it you need to build your library and add it to some repository, such as maven central.

Comment: Is there any tutorial to do this ?